# Remote MySQL connection through SSH taking long time

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I fetch data from remote Mysql database through SSH to my local SQL server and then delete all data from remote server; in my C# ASP.net application(running in IIS). It was running quite fine since friday but today the connection is terribly slow. My code for connection is:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("vps.abc.com", 22, "username", "password"))
            {
                client.Connect();

                var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3307, "localhost", 3306);
                client.AddForwardedPort(port);

                port.Start();

                string connstr = "server=127.0.0.1;user=" + "user" + ";database=database;port=" + "3307" + ";password=" + "password" + ";";
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT * from formstable ORDER BY id DESC ", conn);
                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            DateTime updated;
                            if (Convert.IsDBNull(dr["updated_at"]))
                            {
                                updated = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["created_at"]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                updated = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["updated_at"]);
                            }
                            var formsquote = new FormsQuote
                            {
                                //id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["id"]),
                                name = dr["name"].ToString(),
                                phone = dr["phone"].ToString()                                
                            };
                            FormsQuoteAdapter.Insert(formsquote);
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("Delete FROM formstable ", conn);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }

                port.Stop();
                client.Disconnect();
```

I checked using breakpoints that the line `client.Connect();` is taking much time. I have no idea whats gone wrong suddenly. Can anyone help me in resolving this. Thank you

Comment: Connecting over SSH can be slow. Can you reproduce this in the [Workbench tool](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

Comment: @tadman thanks for quick reply. Yes, I can connect through workbench and its not that slow

Comment: You may need to investigate what part of this is causing trouble. Is it SSH negotation? Is it the MySQL connection phase? Is it running the query? There's a lot going on here, you'll need to carefuly examine each step. If you can, print out timestamps to help with your diagnosis so you know the rough timing and can pin-point the issue.

Comment: I have no idea how can i check this. Do i need to check in Mysql workbench? query in workbench takes 0.016 sec

Comment: I'm talking about the time for the whole ordeal, from initiating the SSH connection to establishing the tunnel to connecting to the MySQL server. That last part is fast. The other steps might be slow.

Comment: ok i understand that i think the connection takes time in establishing as in my code the line client.connect() takes time

Comment: I also started getting this error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted; after few minutes. If its causing problem